# The slowness about Websphere Application Server's app Admin Console

Tags: websphere

It's the concern about Admin console's performance from Websphere Application Server. 
I can login smoothly without any problem, but it's got be very slow on response when doing operations such as showing Node status by clicking "Nodes" under "System administration", showing AppServer status by clicking "Application Servers" under "Servers" etc. However, the funny thing is the problem is more serious on remote node than the local nodes which locate on same box with DmgrNode.
So i suspect it should be the problem with network communication between DmgrNode and remote Node, but i don't know how to fix it. 
Anybody got the same issue here??? Or any idea to figure it out? Please do me a favor, please please .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the console gets the list of servers to display, it does make mbean calls to all of the servers, and if there is a network problem between the dmgr and the node, this could cause some delay in displaying the server page.   The nodes page, however, should not have that issue.  What is your topology?  How many nodes/servers and how many are local/remote?

How can you tell the problem is more serious on the remote nodes than the local nodes?
Are other console operations slower, or only ones that display status?  Do you have the same problem with wsadmin commands?   The console issues a queryNames to search for the server mbeans.  Does the following wsadmin command run much more slowly on the remote node than the local node?  If so, how much more slowly?

```
print AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=Server,node=myNode')
```

Replace myNode with either the local or remote node name.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using IE to fire up the console. Fire the console from Chrome and see if it helps.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what grounds did you base that solution and assumption?